# Can we directly run place the jar file under the local maven repository without specyfing the dependency under pom.xml file

Tags: maven-2

I have imported an existing Maven Project into Eclipse , this has got a lot of dependency with other jars

Please tell me can i directly run mvn install path to My jar file command  , without specifying dependency tag on to the POM.xml file ??

In simple terms my question was , can we simple run this command without specifying any  dependency inside the POm.xml file .

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=<MVN_GROUPID> -DartifactId=<MVN_ARTIFACTID> -Dversion=<MVN_VERSION> -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=<JAR_FILE_TO_INSTALL>
```

Thank you .

Comment: Are you trying to install the artifact from your Maven project or some other JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly run this command without modifying or adding dependencies to the `pom.xml` file. Note that the artifact will be installed in your local repository without the `pom.xml`. So the information about the project dependencies will be lost to any artifacts dependant on this project.

A much easier way to install the artifact in your local repository, with the `pom.xml`, is by executing the following command:

```
mvn install
```

Do you have reason to avoid this command?